# What is the path to Lightning SVG icons in a sandbox?

Tags: lightning-design-system, sandbox, svg-icon, spring-20

So far I have found and tried three paths, but none of them is resulting in an icon being displayed.

I am using this code, provided by [Salesforce](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/):

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
        <svg class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
        </svg>
        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder Text" class="slds-input" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't display any icon. With googling I found other paths:

- {!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS213, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search'}
- /resource/slds214/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search

I am doing this in a Spring '20 sandbox.

Comment: you using vf pages or component?

Comment: Inside a Lightning Web Component

Comment: why not simply use lightning input of type seacrh or lightning icon if you want to make custom.

Comment: I thought I was using the standard search input text. Forgive me, I am a newbie in LWC development. To which component are you referring?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Lw_ag-RW/1/edit

Comment: Thank you, this is much easier to use. I thought I was looking in the official documentation for Lightning, but apparently I wasn't. Still, the question itself has not been answered, I'll leave it open for a while.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two locations, one for Lightning, and one for Visualforce.

## Lightning

Replace the `/assets/` of any URL in the Lightning Design System with `/_slds/`. Example:

```
/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search
```

Note: It is **strongly** recommended that you simply use lightning:icon, lightning:buttonIcon, etc, when using SLDS in a supported environment.

## Visualforce

Add `/apexpages/slds/latest` to the beginning of the URL. Example:

```
/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search
```

I would recommend using Lightning Out instead of plain Visualforce in order to provide a migration path forward to Lightning, but you can use that resource as a stopgap to allow your Visualforce pages to operate whilst migrating your code to Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to obtain the proper URL for lightning icons from a Visualforce page, the correct syntax is as follows:

`{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}`

Please see the Visualforce Developer Guide for more information:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_asset.htm